# Add target="_blank" for links not working after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, attr

I'm using this jQuery snippet to make all links in that section open up in a new tab. It works fine until I make an ajax call. Then this script has no effect.

Any idea how to optimise it for ajax?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

  $("#my-section a").attr("target","_blank");
  
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Torsten

Answer (score 0):

I kept on fiddling using ".on" and this seems to work:

```
jQuery("#my-section").on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    jQuery("#my-section a").attr("target","_blank");

});
```

:-)